# Remove absolute position generated by GWT

Tags: css, gwt

In my web page, I have a menu (`HorizontalPanel`) that should be stached to the buttom of the page. To do that, I've tried to use the `RootLayoutPanel` class and add a south widget in it and I succeeded to do that. but the problem is that the menu is not centered.
I tried to add another CSS in which I wrote(and notice the position):

```
.cetrer {
    Margin-left : auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

But when the page is redered, the position is set to absolute by GWT.
And I tried to force the position by adding this lign to the code but it didn't work:

```
DOM.setElementAttribute(menuBar.getElement(), "style", "position: relative;");
```

So is there any solution to fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `!important;` ?
Like:

```
.cetrer {
    Margin-left : auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Not the best solution though.

Comment: Waw! Thanks a lot for the solution but is this tag (!important) from the W3C or it is made by the GWT community?

Comment: Nothing to do with GWT, it's been in CSS since CSS1 :). Although as this solution is quick and dirty, I'd recommend you find out how to do it with GWT.

Comment: Ah! OK I've found this link http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm. Thanks a lot for your help.