# Styling a GWT Button with CSS

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to apply css with GWT `Button` widget, however I can apply CSS gradient, the "embossed"  style of the widget is still there. How can I remove that?

My gwt application is inherting from this theme:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
```

Als have tried:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
```

I also have tried adding:

```
.gwt-Button {}
```

In the main css file that is loaded on the page however the embossed style is still there.

Anyone knows how to remove the embossed style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid using GWT default style, I just use `!important` tag in my CSS file. You'll find here an example of doing so : [Remove absolute position generated by GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096036/remove-absolute-position-generated-by-gwt). Good luck!

Comment: My custom css is applied, the only problem is the embossed style which  I need to get rid off.

Answer (score 10):

#### Option 1: Not using themes at all

If you don't need the default styles, and generally want to give the page your own style, then it's easiest to completely omit the `<inherits>` statement for the themes. GWT works very well without using a theme.

<sup>(Note: If you still need the (image) resources from the theme, but without injecting the CSS stylesheet into the page, you can inherit `com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.CleanResources` instead of `com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean`. This way they will still be copied automatically to your war folder.)</sup>

#### Option 2: Selectively turning off theming for buttons

If however you generally want to use a theme, and only need to give some buttons your own style, then an easy solution is calling

```
button.removeStyleName("gwt-Button");
```

<sup>Note: Instead of `removeStyleName()` you could also use `setStyleName("my-Button")`.</sup>

For convenience (and for easier usage in UiBinder) you may want to derive your own class like

```
package org.mypackage;

public class MyStyleButton extends Button {
    public MyStyleButton(final String html) {
        super(html);
        removeStyleName("gwt-Button");
    }

    /* ... override all the other Button constructors similarly ... */
}
```

Which can then be imported and used in UiBinder like

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:my='urn:import:org.mypackage'>

    ...

       <my:MyStyleButton>...
```

#### Option 3: Actually changing the gwt-Button class attributes

If you want to keep the themed look of the buttons, and only change a few style attributes, then it's also possible to overwrite certain attributes in the predefined style classes with `!important` (as suggested by @bouhmid_tun). But be careful: The list of attributes might change in the future. Here are all the predefined style classes for `.gwt-Button` of GWT 2.4.0 for your convenience:

```
.gwt-Button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size:small;
  background: url("images/hborder.png") repeat-x 0px -2077px;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.gwt-Button:active {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.gwt-Button:hover {
  border-color: #939393;
}
.gwt-Button[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  color: #888;
}
.gwt-Button[disabled]:hover {
  border: 1px outset #ccc;
}
```

Comment: but I got this when doing like this. 09:19:03.273 [INFO] [esewaAdmin] Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or using an @external declaration for unobfuscated classe