# Styling widgets with GWT: where to put style rules?

Tags: css, gwt, styling

One of my widgets contain a programmatically generated list of `ToggleButton`s. I would like to style them, but I'm not sure what the best approach is. GWT provides rules like `.gwt-ToggleButton-up` and `.gwt-ToggleButton-Down` that I could override. I am able to override these by putting my rules in a `style.css` file and referencing it from my HTML file (although that approach is deprecated).

If I include the following in the UiBinder that contains the buttons, the styles aren't applied:

```
<ui:style>
  .gwt-ToggleButton-down {
      color: red;
  }

  .gwt-ToggleButton-up {
      color: red;
  }
</ui:style>
```

(I'm guessing that has to do with how GWT obfuscates CSS names.)

I could also make a new UiBinder component that just wraps `ToggleButton` to apply my own style rules, but that may be unnecessarily cumbersome.

Should I ignore the `.gwt-ToggleButton-*` rules entirely and define my own rules, applying them with `toggleButton.addStyleName()`? Or is another approach preferable?

Comment: There are several options, depending if you want to use pre-defined themes or not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10478824/291741 Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

`@external` will prevent obfuscation if that's the route you want to go.

```
<ui:style>
  @external gwt-ToggleButton-down, gwt-ToggleButton-up;
  .gwt-ToggleButton-down {
      color: red;
  }
  .gwt-ToggleButton-up {
      color: red;
  }
</ui:style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the styles into **.css** file which is located under **war** folder.