# How to use buttons with GWT's UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

In MyPanel.ui.xml:

```
<button class="btn" ui:field="myButton">Save</button>
```

In MyPanel.java:

```
public class MyPanel extends Composite {
    ...
    @UiField ButtonElement myButtonUi;
    ...
    public MyScreen() {
        final HTMLPanel panel = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
        initWidget(panel);
        Button myButton = Button.wrap(myButtonUi);
```

In MyEntryPoint.java:

```
if (....)
    RootPanel.get().add(new MyPanel());
```

So I think I don't really understand how to use UiBinder.

It's my intention to use HTML with ui:field=".." so that the web-designer can set things like class="xx" on the UI fields. Most of the GWT documentation assumes you've got a Button not a ButtonElement. But if I use a Button I need to have a `<g:Button>` in the HTML document which means my web-designer can't set the class? I mean the point of UiBinder is to allow one to use normal HTML and integrate it with the GWT code?

When I do the above, on the wrap line, I get a NullPointerException in development mode from:

```
public static Button wrap(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element) {
    // Assert that the element is attached.
    assert Document.get().getBody().isOrHasChild(element);
```

In production mode it seems to work OK. In the debugger of development mode in Eclipse, when I right-click and "Inspect" the expression "Document.get().getBody()" Eclipse says "Cannot send a static message to a non class type object".

What should I do? Is the null pointer exception happening because I need to attach the element first? If so, how? (I am already calling createAndBindUi and the element passed to wrap is non-null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, here's the answer. I Edited it and deleted useless comments.

You can't use HTML in your ui.xml if your plan is to use UiBinder to wire a component from the ui.xml to your view's Java code. Instead of

```
<button class="btn" ui:field="myButton">Save</button>
```

use

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
<g:Button styleName="btn" text="Save" ui:field="myButton"/>
```

Then in your view -java code- simply type

```
@UiField com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button myButton;

public MyScreen() {
    final HTMLPanel panel = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    initWidget(panel);
}
```

That's it.

The "styleName" attribute is enough for your designer to hook a CSS class. [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472098/styling-a-gwt-button-with-css) might interest you. Designers will have to learn about what attributes are available on which components. Using UiBinder is not as straighforward as using HTML.

UiBinder is not for writing HTML but to write XML that can be understood by GWT and compiled to javascript (which in turn will produce the page's HTML). It's not like the JSP mechanism where you can insert plain HTML right away.

UiBinder is most helpful when you have to wire ui elements (widgets or composites from the ui.xml) with your Java view code (i.e. using the @UiField or @UiHandler annotations).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alas that doesn't work, if I have `@UiField Button` but a `<button>` in the HTML, I get: Type mismatch: Cannot connvert from ButtonElement to Button.

Comment: "UiBinder is not for writing HTML but.." this is a shame, HTML generally comes from designers even in interactive apps like one can create with GWT. The overview of UiBinder specifically states "makes it easier to collaborate with UI designers who are more comfortable with XML, HTML and CSS than Java source code;" so from this I took it I could take HTML from the designer, add ui:field to the appropriate elements, then manipulate them from GWT. Hmm. That would certainly be a useful feature.

Comment: .ui.xml header is `<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'><g:HTMLPanel>` and the line with the button in the HTML has nothing more than in my question.

Comment: I agree. From our designer's point of view it was much easier to work with JSP or Html+Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, although I don't "like" this approach from a philosophical viewpoint, I think you are right, that .ui.xml is not for entering HTML. Ignoring the objective of entering HTML did allow me to get it working. P.S. Don't know who/why someone downvoted you.

Comment: addStyleNames  will allow you to add multiple class names to an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML. The only restriction is that `g:Button` must be inside a container like `g:HTMLPanel`.
The good thing about `g:HTMLPanel` is that it can render HTML.

See the example below:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>       
    <div>
    test
    </div>

    <table border="1">
    <th>
        button
    </th>
    <tr>
    <td>    
    <g:Button styleName="{style.important}" ui:field="button"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
    test
    </div>      
</g:HTMLPanel>
```